# What is it called, when you add a new actionlistener with a method while already in a method?

Tags: java, methods, actionlistener

Just to make sure, this is what I mean:

```
public static void someMethod()
{
    JButton btn = new JButton();
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            // Do something...
        }
    });
}
```

So when adding an ActionListener to the button, I create a new ActionListener and a new method inside a method - but what is this implementation of an ActionListener called?

Comment: anonymous method i think, or anonymous class

Comment: [Anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: *anonymous **inner** class*